# What is this character "" and why does it cause a line break?

Tags: node.js, layout, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars + hbs (following the block/extend helper example) to render html for my node application.  For some reason, one of my div's is getting pushed down 1 line.

I checked the dom inspector in chrome, and there's a line with double quotes:

[image: hated double quotes]

Which causes this:
[image: hated double quotes result]

When I remove the double quotes from the dom inspector (press backspace or delete) the layout is correct:
[image]

[image]

What the crap is going on?  Is it a non-printing character or something?  There's nothing in the html/template, and a blank space (or whatever character that is) shouldn't cause a block level element to change position, right?

**Here's some code:**
The relevant section of Layout.html

```
<div id="details" class="east">{{{block "east"}}}</div>
```

The template:

```
<div id="details-title">
  <h3 class="title elide" style="height:26px;">{{Title}}</h3>
</div>
<div id="details-body" class="content text">
  <img class="card" src="{{ImagePath}}" />
  <div>
    <span class="type">{{Type}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    {{{Body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The block + extend helpers: ([from the hbs example](https://github.com/donpark/hbs/blob/master/examples/extend/app.js))

```
hbs.registerHelper("extend", function (name, context) {
    var block = blocks[name];
    if (!block) {
        block = blocks[name] = [];
    }

    if (typeof context.fn !== "undefined") {
        block.push(context.fn(this));
    }
});

hbs.registerHelper("block", function (name) {
    var val = (blocks[name] || [])
        .filter(function () { return true })
        .join("\n");

    // clear the block
    blocks[name] = [];
    return val;
});
```

**Update**
Apparently, this is [char 65279](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm), my precompiled handlebars templates all emit this as the first character when rendered.

Comment: What does the template look like? What data are you feeding it? What does the generate HTML look like? What CSS is in effect?

Comment: You should post your hbs so that people can see what might be producing the extra ""

Comment: @muistooshort I guess my point is that I've already ruled out the css, template and data.  I'm trying to figure out what character that "" is and why it causes a line break.  The title of the question is probably bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added a hack to remove the BOM that appears as the first character in the template output:

```
var html = detailTemplate(res.data);
if (html.charCodeAt(0) === 65279) { // hack to fix precompiled hbs template bug
  html = html.substring(1);
}
$("#details").html(html);
```

It turns out that the block + extend helpers have nothing to do with the problem.  I'm assuming it's a problem with the encoding I'm using, but I'm not sure how to change that.  The above code fixes the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Save with Encoding > UTF-8